# Problemas copiando datos a archivo csv (a bytes-like object is required, not 'str')

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy teniendo problemas para copiar una columna de datos en un archivo csv.

El archivo csv original es algo así:

```
ID;texto
1;El niño juega
2;La rana salta
3;Mi código no funciona
```

El código que uso lee unos datos de un archivo csv, y genera una lista. Luego intento pegar esa lista en otro csv. Hago lo siguiente:

```
import csv
with open("scraped.csv", "r", encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='unix', delimiter = ",")
    sent =[]
    for row in reader:
        sent.append(row["texto"])
with open("results.csv", 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='unix', delimiter=",",
                        quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(['texto'])
    writer.writerow([sent])
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Probando 2.py", line 46, in 
    writer.writerow(['texto'])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

El objetivo es poder copiar en el nuevo csv file cada frase en una fila, bajo el título texto.

Gracias por las sugerencias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estas intentando guardar texto (cadena codificada) en un archivo binario (`wb`). `writer.writerow` espera una cadena de texto (que es lo que le pasas) no bytes, simplemente abre el archivo de escritura en modo texto (`'w'` en vez de `'wb'`):

```
import csv

with open("Libro.csv", "r", encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    with open("results.csv", 'w', encoding="utf8") as csv_out:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='unix', delimiter = ",")
        writer  = csv.writer(csv_out, dialect='unix', delimiter=",",
                             quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writerow(["texto"])
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow([row["texto"]])
```

---

**Edición:**

Si quieres usar la lista como haces en tu código basta con que iteres sobre ella:

```
for item in sent:
    writer.writerow([item])
```

O bien usar `writer.writerows` y un generador:

```
import csv

with open("Libro.csv", "r", encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='unix', delimiter = ",")
    sent =[]
    for row in reader:
        sent.append(row["texto"])

with open("results.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='unix', delimiter=",",
                        quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(['texto'])
    writer.writerows([row] for row in sent)
```

Comment: Sin embargo, ¿y si se deseara utilizar la lista creada y copiar cada elemento en una fila del nuevo csv file?

Comment: justo lo que estaba intentando... mil gracias